# Python Pandas Dataframe adding extra column based on duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

today I have been working on merging and editing data frames and I have been stuck with a very specific part. I have a column with names of certain fruit and then names of a person like this:

| Fruit | Person |
| --- | --- |
| Banana | Jake |
| Banana | Paul |
| Carrot | Nancy |
| Carrot | Sydney |
| Carrot | Jane |

Note that the "Person" column will always be unique. My goal is to get something like this with a third or fourth column:

| Fruit | Person1 | Person2 | Person3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Banana | Jake | Paul |  |
| Carrot | Nancy | Sydney | Jane |

I've tried this:

```
first = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Zone','District','Area'],keep='First',inplace = True)
second = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Zone','District','Area'],keep='Last',inplace = True)
```

and merging them together later but this will not get those that are in the middle such as "Syndey" from my example. I found this:
[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530856/how-to-keep-first-two-duplicates-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

But I don't really understand the `groupby` part. I hope this helps and thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @MayankPorwal I am super new to this still!

Comment: Solution is in dupe in Q/A no.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.groupby`, `Groupby.agg` and `pd.concat`:

```
In [890]: df1 = df.groupby('Fruit').agg(list).reset_index()
In [905]: res = pd.concat([df1.Fruit, pd.DataFrame(df1.Person.tolist(), index=df1.index)], 1)

In [906]: res
Out[906]: 
    Fruit      0       1     2
0  Banana   Jake    Paul  None
1  Carrot  Nancy  Sydney  Jane
```

Comment: Great answer worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.assign(_=lambda x: 'Person'+(x.groupby('Fruit').transform(
    'cumcount')+1).astype(str)).pivot(columns='_', index='Fruit')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
        Person                
_      Person1 Person2 Person3
Fruit                         
Banana    Jake    Paul     NaN
Carrot   Nancy  Sydney    Jane
```